# Assigning covariate associated to spatial points to a bigger set of spatial points in R?

Tags: r, geospatial, r-raster

I have two data sets with spatial points (in .csv format): data1 with 220 spatial points with latitude and longitude and data2 with 80 spatial points with latitude and longitude. For data2 I have one covariate indicated the genetic origin of each points. Spatial points in both datasets are not exactly the same.

I would like to assign the genetic origin for spatial points in data1. It seems that I need to define around each point in data2 a square (or other) to be able to associate a genetic origin at each points in data1.

I am using R and I think packages as raster or sp may be useful.

Thanks for your help.

Best,
Marie.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your mind up about how you want to assign "genetic origin". One approach that seem to be hinting at is assigning it to its nearest neighbor.

When asking a question you should always include some example data.

```
library(raster)
d1 <- data.frame(lon=c(1,5,55,31), lat=c(3,7,20,22))
d2 <- data.frame(lon=c(4,2,8,65,5,4), lat=c(50,-90,20,32,10,10), origin=LETTERS[1:6], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Here is how you can assign origin based on the nearest known origin

```
# make sure your data are (x,y) or (longitude,latitude), not the reverse
pd <- pointDistance(d1, d2[,1:2], lonlat=TRUE)
nd <- apply(pd, 1, which.min)
d1$origin <- d2$origin[nd]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It is exactly what I was looking for.